# Hibernate MappedSuperClass in another project

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

We are building a complex project which will consist of multiple projects. And amongst these projects, two of them will be used generally for defining base entities (like interfaces).

Normally, if these all projects were one it would run without any error with the codes below.

But with these codes placed in seperate projects, the entities which derived from the superclass (from the BaseEntity) are causing this error :

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: com.unalcable.department.security.model.ApprovalHistory
```

So I've searched for causes, and I've found out that defining BaseEntity in Hibernate's configuration like a concrete class like other would fix it. But it didn't...

Here are the codes :

**Hibernate's configuration**

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
            <property name="annotatedClasses">
                <list>
                    <value>com.unalcable.general.common.model.BaseEntity</value>
                    <value>com.unalcable.department.security.model.ApprovalHistory</value>
                    <value>com.unalcable.department.security.model.CarVisitorRequest</value>
                    <value>com.unalcable.department.security.model.HumanVisitorRequest</value>
                    <value>com.unalcable.department.security.model.Privilige</value>
                    <value>com.unalcable.department.security.model.Visitor</value>
                </list>
            </property>
            <property name="hibernateProperties">
                <props>
                    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.showSql}</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.action}</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${hibernate.format_sql}</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">${hibernate.use_sql_comments}</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers">true</prop>
                </props>
            </property>
        </bean>
```

**BaseEntity.java (in Project 1)**

```
    @MappedSuperclass
    @Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
    public class BaseEntity implements Serializable 
    {
        public static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


        public Long id;

        public String toString() {
            return ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(this, ToStringStyle.DEFAULT_STYLE);
        }

        public boolean equals(Object obj)
        {
            boolean result = false;
            if (obj instanceof BaseEntity) {
                BaseEntity other = (BaseEntity)obj;
                if (other.getId().equals(this.getId())) result = true;
            }
            return result;
        }

        public String toDebugString()
        {
            return ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(this, ToStringStyle.DEFAULT_STYLE);
        }

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        public Long getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(Long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

    }
```

**ApprovalHistory.java(Project 2)**

```
    @Entity

    public class ApprovalHistory extends BaseEntity {

        public long date;
        public User user;

        @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
        public ApprovalState approvalState;

        public long getDate() {
            return date;
        }
        public void setDate(long date) {
            this.date = date;
        }
        public User getUser() {
            return user;
        }
        public void setUser(User user) {
            this.user = user;
        }
        public ApprovalState getApprovalState() {
            return approvalState;
        }
        public void setApprovalState(ApprovalState approvalState) {
            this.approvalState = approvalState;
        }

    }
```

** All projects refer to necessary projects in build path. Also Tomcat has these projects in its classpath **

Answer (score 0):

The error you get might be caused by mixed access type. BaseEntity declares `@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)` while ApprovalHistory has an annotated field so Hibernate assumes it uses FIELD access type. I'm not sure about this, but it may be trying to apply FIELD access to your base entity as well, thus not finding the identifier.

Try moving the `@Enumerated` annotation to the `getApprovalState()` method to see if it is the case.

Comment: I have tried both @Access(AccessType.PROPERTY) and @Access(AccessType.FIELD). It still doesn't work.

Comment: Did you try moving the @Enumerated annotation to the getter as I suggested?